# changing the rails env. to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

My rails app is working just fine when it is in development mode however if I change it to production mode, it gives something wrong error and I cannot see any reason behind it. Do you know any possible problem ?

This is my error message:

```
Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 30 00:55:16 +0300 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:132:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:241:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:181:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:65:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.1) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/erogol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /home/erogol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /home/erogol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /home/erogol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /home/erogol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /home/erogol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /home/erogol/.rvm/ru
```

Thanks all cares...

when I type rake assets:precompile I got:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- uglifier
  (in /home/erogol/Dropbox/Bunch_It/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/erogol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/b...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: There can be zillion causes for this :)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please copy/paste the exact error message. Also, did you migrate the production database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about the `config.assets.compress = true`. It creates problem about my javascript files. I set it false and my app start to work just fine. However I do not know whether making it false causes any loss of my program.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `\config\environments\production.rb` file. That helped me.

Answer (score 1):

from the error message, it is said that Rails can't find the file:  /favicon.ico. please make sure it exists.

Comment: it exists. I guess the problem is about caching or something like that. But I cannot figure out yet.

Comment: where it exists? which folder? did you used asset pipeline? is it accessbile for your rails server? (e.g. mod 755)

Answer (score 1):

My first guess if this is only in production and not in development is you may need to compile your assets. You would need to either run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

or change your `production.rb` environment file to include:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

However, the path in the error mesage is just `/favicon.ico` not `assets/favicon.ico`. And, the favicon file should just be in your `/public` directory. Can you confirm that this is where the file is located?

Comment: I did as you said, I change location of favicon to public folder and change the references however still it gives same errors. In addition in development mode Why does not give the error about favicon, if its location was wrong?

Comment: In addition rake assets:precompile did not work so I just change the production.rb as you say.

Comment: Well, does your gemfile include `uglifier`?